# Is it possible to alter the json response from inside a webpack proxy?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am calling an api which returns much more data than I need, and in an ugly json format.
I would like to be able the map the response to return something nicer.

For example if I am only interested in the customer name, I would like to do something like:

```
'/api': {
    target: 'http://test.com/',
    onProxyRes: function(proxyRes, req, res){
        res.body = {
            customerName = res.body.ACME_Customer.ACME_Name
        }
    }
}
```

But of course there is no res.body.  I seem to have access only the http headers, not the body.

<sub>I know I can just map the response later in JavaScript but I would ideally like to do it at the proxy level so that:

 1. my application code is cleaner

 2. my network tab isn't filled with junk</sub>